# Split single row value to multiple rows in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where the column data has a combination of values seperated by ';'. I would like to split them into rows for each column value.

Table data
[image]

Now I would like to split them into multiple rows for each value like

[image]

I have tried using the below SQL statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE,
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=>SPLIT(COL_NAME,';'))
```

But the output is not as expected. Attaching the query output below.

[image]

Basically the query does nothing to my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using LATERAL FLATTERN like a joining table and selecting the value from it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.VALUE AS COL_NAME 
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE", 
LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(COL_NAME,';')A
```

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 5):

It could be achieved using [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) table function:

> This table function splits a string (based on a specified delimiter) and flattens the results into rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(column_name, ';')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks your data has multiple delimiters , We can leverage STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE function using multiple delimiters..

[STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html)

```
 WITH data AS (
 SELECT *
    FROM VALUES
           ('Greensboro-High Point-Winston-Salem;Norfolk-Portsmouth-Newport News Washington, D.C. Roanoke-Lynchburg Richmond-Petersburg')
              v( cities))
select * 
    from data, lateral strtok_split_to_table(cities, ';-')
    order by seq, index;
```

## **Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was very close, you just need to access the out of the flatten, instead of the input to the flatten

so using this CTE for data:

```
 WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES
    ('Greensboro-High Point-Winston-Salem;Norfolk-Portsmouth-Newport News;Washington, D.C.;Roanoke-Lynchburg;Richmond-Petersburg'),
    ('Knoxville'),
    ('Knoxville;Memphis;Nashville')
    v( COL_NAME)
 )
```

if you had aliased you tables, and accessed the parts.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT f.value::text as col_name
 FROM fake_data d,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=>SPLIT(COL_NAME,';')) f
;
```

which is what you did in your provided answer, but via SPLIT_TO_TABLE

```
 SELECT DISTINCT f.value as col_name
 FROM fake_data d,
    TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(COL_NAME,';')) f
;
```

STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE also is the same thing:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT f.value as col_name
 FROM fake_data d,
    TABLE(strtok_split_to_table(COL_NAME,';')) f
;
```

Which can also be done via a strtok_to_array and FLATTEN that

```
 SELECT DISTINCT f.value as col_name
 FROM fake_data d,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(COL_NAME,';'))) f
;
```

| COL_NAME |
| --- |
| Greensboro-High Point-Winston-Salem |
| Norfolk-Portsmouth-Newport News |
| Washington, D.C. |
| Roanoke-Lynchburg |
| Richmond-Petersburg |
| Knoxville |
| Memphis |
| Nashville |